# Strange CSS3 animation issue in IE11 and Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations, microsoft-edge

I made a CSS3 animation, it works well in Firefox and Chrome, but it behaves differently in IE11 and Edge.

I couldn't fix the issue because it's hard to debug CSS3 Animation using IE Developer Tools. This issue also occurs on Edge (But i think my Edge version is outdated so please try to reproduce this issue only in IE11. The fix will probably work on both).

---

#### Here is how i want the animation to look (Works on Chrome/Firefox):

[image]

---

#### Here is how it animates differently on IE11:

[image]

---

#### Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="block"></div>
<span>click</span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.block {
  position: fixed;
  height: 0%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #0B0B0B;
  z-index: 99999;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.animate-up {
    animation-name: overlayEffectUp;
  }


@keyframes overlayEffectUp {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
    top: auto;
    height: 0%;
  }

  35%,
  65% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    bottom: auto;
    top: 0;
    height: 0%;
  }
}
```

JavaScript (With jQuery):

```
$('span').on('click', function() {
    $('.block').addClass('animate-up')
})
```

Here is the Demo link: https://jsfiddle.net/zoq9h7xp/3/

Please, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I tried many variations but nothing fix the issue for IE browser. It can be possible that this is some kind of bug in IE and Edge browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge seems to be buggy with `position: fixed`. Supposedly the switch between `top: 0` and `top: auto` (and same story with the `bottom` property) causes this behaviour.

If you must maintain the `fixed` position, you can try to animate with the `transform` property. Change your rulesets as follow:

```
@keyframes overlayEffectUp {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(100%); // totally offscreen
    }

    35%,
    65% {
        transform: translateY(0%); // totally on screen from bottom
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-100%); // totally off screen again to top
    }
}
.block {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0B0B0B;
    z-index: 99999;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers, Jeroen